Get M365 search suggestions of SharePoint Online in PnP search box web part
SharePoint Online site search box gives suggestions in the search box as displayed below:

We wanted to display same search suggestions in PnP search box web part using external suggestions providers. To get the data, we tried SharePoint rest API suggestions but it returns the different output and is not matching with the above displayed suggestions results.
After digging in the browser's developer tool Network panel, we saw some API endpoints starts with https://substrate.office.com/search/api/v1/suggestions?query=dikesh..... returns the same results that we expected.
We don't have much information about Microsoft Substrate. I guess it was first introduced by Microsoft in Ignite 2019. Substrate services are the critical component of the Microsoft services. It holds all the data of Office 365 tenant and this service is being used under Search services along with Intune and AI to generate the results.
So questions are:

How can we utilize this substrate API to get this same suggestions results?
If not with substrate API, then Is there any alternative available to achieve the same search suggestions?

References:

https://petri.com/microsoft-365-substrate-intelligent-search/
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/video-hub/admin-39-s-guide-to-the-microsoft-365-substrate/ba-p/3633132

